# Why is sum of 2 rolls is not calculated another way?

Tags: probability, self-learning

> **Question:** what is the probability of getting a sum of 5 using a pair of dice?

I am aware of the solution being, choosing one face for each dice - that gives total $36$ possibilities in the sample space

For the event space, only the sum of $(1,4), (4,1), (2,3), (3,2)$ equals to 5, so probability of getting a sum of $5$ is $4/36$.

=======================================================================================

Why is the solution not approached in another way?

That is, since the sum of 2 dice can only lead to $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12$ i.e. $11$ possibilites, the probability of getting 5 as sum is $1/11$. Why is this method wrong, and how is the approach wrong?

I want to know the fundamental behind this. I am confused and not getting the intution behind. Thanks!

Comment: Is $5/36$ a typo for $4/36$?

Comment: The question "Is the sum $5$?" has only two possible answers, Yes or No, so I think the probability should be $1/2$.

Comment: If you buy a ticket to the lottery, there are two possible outcomes: either you win the grand prize, or you don't.

Comment: No, I am not asking if the sum is 5 or not. I am asking the probability of getting sum 5. Also, I don't know how it is different from your sum is 5 or not question. Can you help? @ilkkachu

Answer (score 2):

If you replace the phrase you have used, "....total $36$
possibilities in the sample space..."  by "...total $36$
possibilities in the **equiprobable** sample space..."  the flaw in the second approach should become self-evident, as a sample space of $11$ is certainly not equiprobable. different sums can occur in a different number of ways.

The two die rolls are independent, and thus produce $6\times6 = 36$ equiprobable outcomes. Writing the outcomes from die $1$ and die $2$ as ordered pairs these are

$(1,1)\;(1,2)\;(1,3)\;(1,4)\;(1,5)\;(1,6)$
$(2,1)\;(2,2)\;(2,3)\;(2,4)\;(2,5)\;(2,6)$
$(3,1)\;(3,2)\;(3,3)\;(3,4)\;(3,5)\;(3,6)$
$(4,1)\;(4,2)\;(4,3)\;(4,4)\;(4,5)\;(4,6)$
$(5,1)\;(5,2)\;(5,3)\;(5,4)\;(5,5)\;(5,6)$
$(6,1)\;(6,2)\;(6,3)\;(6,4)\;(6,5)\;(6,6)$

We can now count the favorable outcomes and compute the probability as $\frac{favorable\; outcomes}{total\; outcomes}\;\;$, as we are dealing with an equiprobable sample space

Comment: But how do you know that the $36$ ordered pairs of die rolls are equally likely? In order for this answer to be complete, you need to mention the fact/assumption that the die rolls are independent.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Have added material as suggested.

Comment: @trueblueanil Can you explain a bit further about equiprobable/equally likely sample spaces, or when it is not? I have read it in books, but I am not getting the complete picture!

Comment: You can have a look at "Experiments Having Equally Likely Outcomes" where it is explained in simple language. https://stats.libretexts.org/Courses/City_University_of_New_York/Introductory_Statistics_with_Probability_(CUNY)/04%3A_Probability_Theory/4.02%3A_Experiments_Having_Equally_Likely_Outcomes

Answer (score 1):

Just to echo @trueblueanil and @DanielC..

The experiment is about tossing a pair of dice so we really have to look at the results of two dice rolls first before calculating the sum. Because going directly to the sum makes you lose valuable information about the experiment ,that is the number of ways an outcome can occur because the mistake in your second approach is you assumed all sums have same number of possibilities to occur.

The first table below shows all possibilities, while the second table shows you how many times a sum can occur.

| First | Second | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 1 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | 7 |
| 6 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 4 | 9 |
| 6 | 4 | 10 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 6 | 5 | 11 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 4 | 6 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 11 |
| 6 | 6 | 12 |

| Sum | Number of Possibilities it occurs |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 2 |
| 12 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

The reason your method does not work is because *the eleven possible sums of the dice, between $2$ and $12$, are **not** equally likely*. Instead, the $36$ possible ordered pairs of numbers rolled by the dice are equally likely. The reason that each pair of numbers is equally likely is a consequence of the fact that the two dice are **independent**. Namely, if we let $X$ be the result of the first die, and $Y$ of the second, then for any numbers $x,y\in \{1,\dots,6\}$,
$$
P(X=x\text{ and }Y=y)\stackrel{\text{indep.}}=P(X=x)P(Y=y)=(1/6)\cdot(1/6)=1/36.
$$
Above, used the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, along with the fact that each value of $X$ is equally likely, and the same for $Y$ (the dice are fair).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sum as you said can be {$1 \cdots 11$}, but you haven't taken into account that both rolls are distinguishable according to the exercise. Therefore, for the number $5$, pairs of rolls could be $(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)$. This is called compositions of a number, and is one of the basic tools of combinatorics.

What you have done is just choosing just one of the possible sums, but for each sum there are many possiblities depending on the pair of rolls. That is why not only it has to be taken into account the possible sums (10 results), but all possible pairs of results.

Comment: "You haven't taken into account that both rolls are distinguishable". I downvoted, because you have not justified _why_ the rolls are distinguishable. If I used identical dice, would the rolls still be distinguishable? The real reason is because the dice are independent. Independence implies that all ordered pairs of outcomes are equally likely.

Comment: @MikeEarnest This was something that was bothering me for quite awhile before I provided my answer. I was wondering as to whether "distinguishable" really plays a factor in this experiment. Because whether it was distinguishable or not, the highest probability in the PMF would still be on $sum=7$. But " Independence implies that all ordered pairs of outcomes are equally likely." really helped bridge my gap in understanding the experiment and what specific theory applies to it. "+1"